# Ways to pass data to ActionMethod when using Hyperlinks

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Other than querystring, is there any other way to pass a value with the redirect (since hyperlinks do not POST) rather than over querystring?  I want to send some stuff to my action method when a hyperlink is clicked but not via route url params..I don't want to always expose them or sometimes they're overly complex strings that would be a nightmare mess in a url to deal with (encoding, etc.).

The viewModel object of mine obviously only persists I think with postbacks and if I'm not wrong, hyperlinks do not post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send other data, you'll need to use a form to submit it via post, or ajax to do the same. Having a form post to an action is pretty painless, though.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("ActionName","ControllerName",FormMethod.Post)){
...
}
```

Comment: right so to answer my question I was right in that a hyperlink won't post and so my only option with just hyperlinks is to send data via querystring to action methods?  I know how to use Html.BeginForm but that's usually with save events (button, etc.)  to do POST, etc.  I guess though it doesn't matter, I can surround the hyperlinks in the form and it WILL post back when clicked?  Not just redirect?  Maybe I just have the fundamentals wrong here

Comment: Yes, hyperlinks are just a "shortcut" to browser's address bar. The only way to pass parameters with hyperlinks is to put them in url (querystring). It doesn't matter if your hyperlinks are inside the form, they won't submit the form unless you use some javascript and onclick handler for hyperlink.

Comment: cool that's what I thought.  So then other than a button, that's pretty much my only option here for postback.

Comment: Also, it isn't necessarily bad to POST without saving. POST is simply POSTing data - which it seems like you want to do.

Comment: well I'm actually wanting to do a GET...What do you mean without saving?  You mean perist posted data to a DB?  yea I need to get a url back so really I'm gonna be doing a GET.  The only problem is, if I use a button, I need to be able to send back a specific value for one of my model properties based on the item I'm clicking submit for.  So the action method will get back a property value from submitting only a certain item that is listed on the page...all items will have a button next to them so every time one of them is clicked I need to send back a certain value for that particular item

Comment: You are not limited in getting a "url" back when doing a post. In fact, MVC implements `RedirectToAction` as an action response. By saving, you said "that's usually with save events". Don't be limited by that, post is a valid way to get data from the client to the server, and you can bounce around between action methods/views from there, returning whatever you desire.

Comment: yea it's just getting this long filepath to my action method, it's a long filepath in the url which makes it messy to work with and how would the action method know where that filepath starts and ends if the filepath itself has a bunch of slashes in it inside the url!

Comment: "Don't be limited by that, post is a valid way to get data from the client to the serve"  What do you mean?  You can only post with some event where the form posts back to an action method.  I guess I don't understand all that can trigger a postback I guess other than web controls